# How to transition to Emoji keyboard from Custom Keyboard when nextKeyboard is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm making a custom keyboard and I want to transition directly to emoji keyboard that is provided by Apple when `nextKeyboard` button is pressed.

```
 @IBAction func nextKeyboardPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        advanceToNextInputMode()
    }
```

This code takes me to the stock keyboard.

[image: Stock iOS]

And I want this keyboard to open when `nextKeyboard` is pressed 
[image: Emoji keyboard]

Is it possible? Is there a way to access stack of installed keyboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. It has been quite limited that the custom keyboard extension to access the external data for some reasons (Especially for security). There is no way to know active keyboards nor change to particuller keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, in the section `Providing a Way to Switch to Another Keyboard` of [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1), Apple says:

> To ask the system to switch to another keyboard, call the
>   advanceToNextInputMode method of the UIInputViewController class. The
>   system picks the appropriate “next” keyboard; there is no API to
>   obtain a list of enabled keyboards or for picking a particular
>   keyboard to switch to.

However, you could modify your Keyboard to contain an Emoji section as well.